# Replacing all NULL values in a h2o data frame efficiently with 0

Tags: python, if-statement, null, h2o

I'm looking for an easy and efficient way to replace all of a certain value in a H2O Python data frame.   In this case this value is NULL.  My dataset contains a very substantial amount of NULLs.

My current way of doing it is extraordinarily slow when I have hundreds of columns in a very large dataset.  I assume there can be substantial improvements by doing this in a better way...

I just can't figure out the syntax.  Thanks, this will save me an enormous amount of time!

My current approach:

```
for each_col in table_names_list:
    h2o_df[h2o_df[each_col].isna(), each_col]=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the special case of NAs, you can use the [`impute()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html?highlight=replace#h2o.frame.H2OFrame.impute) method to replace all of them with a single value (or alternatively, you can impute the mean, median or mode of a column).  Here is an example:

```
import h2o

h2o.init()

df = h2o.H2OFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
df.insert_missing_values(fraction=0.5, seed=1)
```

So the frame will look like this:

```
  C1    C2    C3
----  ----  ----
 nan   nan     3
 nan     5   nan
```

Now we can impute by value, but we need to pass along a list of values which is the same length as the number of columns (and in your case, all zeros).

```
df.impute(column=-1, values=[0 for c in range(df.ncol)])
```

Now the frame looks like this:

```
  C1    C2    C3
----  ----  ----
   0     0     3
   0     5     0
```

Comment: How to impute missing values(I dont see 'nan' in my DF) for only one column? Thanks.